# update lat and lng in mysqli database when I drag marker

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, mysqli

I have a map that has many markers loaded from mysqli database. I have used this tutorial ( https://www.sanwebe.com/2013/10/google-map-v3-editing-saving-marker-in-database )  to get to this point. What i need is to be able to drag the markers and update the database when the markers are moved. I have added a listener to the dragend that calls a function. I tried to add an update_marker function but it doesnt work.  I am not sure whether to try to update using the ID or maptitle - all markers will have different names in the db.  Any direction would be helpful. Thanks.

index.php

```
//############### Create Marker Function ##############
function create_marker(MapPos, MapTitle, MapDesc,  InfoOpenDefault, DragAble, Removable, iconPath)
{                 

    //new marker
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: MapPos,
        map: map,
        draggable:DragAble,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        title: MapTitle,
        icon: iconPath
    });

    //Content structure of info Window for the Markers
    var contentString = $('<div class="marker-info-win">'+
    '<div class="marker-inner-win"><span class="info-content">'+
    '<h1 class="marker-heading">'+MapTitle+'</h1>'+
    MapDesc+'</h1>'+
    iconPath+ 
    '</span><button name="remove-marker" class="remove-marker" title="Remove Marker">Remove Marker</button>'+
    '</div></div>');    


    //Create an infoWindow
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    //set the content of infoWindow
    infowindow.setContent(contentString[0]);

    //Find remove button in infoWindow
    var removeBtn   = contentString.find('button.remove-marker')[0];
    var saveBtn     = contentString.find('button.save-marker')[0];


    //add click listner to remove marker button
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(removeBtn, "click", function(event) {
        remove_marker(marker);
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
        var mytitle = marker.getTitle(); //get marker position
        update_marker(marker, mytitle);
            alert('Marker dropped');
            alert(mytitle);
            });


    if(typeof saveBtn !== 'undefined') //continue only when save button is present
    {
        //add click listner to save marker button
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(saveBtn, "click", function(event) {
            var mReplace = contentString.find('span.info-content'); //html to be replaced after success
            var mName = contentString.find('input.save-name')[0].value; //name input field value
            var mDesc  = contentString.find('textarea.save-desc')[0].value; //description input field value
            var mType = contentString.find('select.save-type')[0].value; //type of marker

            if(mName =='' || mDesc =='')
            {
                alert("Please enter Name and Description!");
            }else{
                save_marker(marker, mName, mDesc, mType, mReplace); //call save marker function
            }
        });
    }

    //add click listner to save marker button        
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map,marker); // click on marker opens info window 
    });

    if(InfoOpenDefault) //whether info window should be open by default
    {
      infowindow.open(map,marker);
    }
}

//############### Remove Marker Function ##############
function remove_marker(Marker)
{


        //Remove saved marker from DB and map using jQuery Ajax
        var mLatLang = Marker.getPosition().toUrlValue(); //get marker position
        var myData = {del : 'true', latlang : mLatLang}; //post variables
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "map_process.php",
          data: myData,
          success:function(data){
                Marker.setMap(null); 
                alert(data);
            },
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                alert(thrownError); //throw any errors
            }
        });
    }

    //############### Update Marker Function ##############
function update_marker(Marker, mytitle)
{


        //Update saved marker from DB and map using jQuery Ajax
        var mLatLang = Marker.getPosition().toUrlValue(); //get marker position
        var mytitle = Marker.getTitle(); //get marker position
        var myData = {update : 'true', name : mytitle, latlang : mLatLang}; //post variables
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "map_process.php",
          data: myData,
          success:function(data){
                alert(data);
            },
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                alert(mLatLang); //throw any errors
            }
        });
    }



//############### Save Marker Function ##############
function save_marker(Marker, mName, mAddress, mType, replaceWin)
{
    //Save new marker using jQuery Ajax
    var mLatLang = Marker.getPosition().toUrlValue(); //get marker position
    var myData = {name : mName, address : mAddress, latlang : mLatLang, type : mType }; //post variables
    console.log(replaceWin);        
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "map_process.php",
      data: myData,
      success:function(data){
            replaceWin.html(data); //replace info window with new html
            Marker.setDraggable(false); //set marker to fixed
            Marker.setIcon('blue-pin.png'); //replace icon
        },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            alert(thrownError); //throw any errors
        }
    });
}

});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
h1.heading{padding:0px;margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;text-align:center;font:     18px Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;}

 /* width and height of google map */
#google_map {width: 90%; height: 500px;margin-top:0px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;}

  /* Marker Edit form */
.marker-edit label{display:block;margin-bottom: 5px;}
.marker-edit label span {width: 100px;float: left;}
 .marker-edit label input, .marker-edit label select{height: 24px;}
.marker-edit label textarea{height: 60px;}
.marker-edit label input, .marker-edit label select, .marker-edit label     textarea {width: 60%;margin:0px;padding-left: 5px;border: 1px solid     #DDD;border-radius: 3px;}

/* Marker Info Window */
h1.marker-heading{color: #585858;margin: 0px;padding: 0px;font: 18px     "Trebuchet MS", Arial;border-bottom: 1px dotted #D8D8D8;}
div.marker-info-win {max-width: 300px;margin-right: -20px;}
div.marker-info-win p{padding: 0px;margin: 10px 0px 10px 0;}
div.marker-inner-win{padding: 5px;}
button.save-marker, button.remove-marker{border: none;background: rgba(0,     0, 0, 0);color: #00F;padding: 0px;text-decoration:     underline;margin-right: 10px;cursor: pointer;
}
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>             
<h1 class="heading">My Google Map</h1>
<div align="center">Right Click to Drop a New Marker</div>
<div id="google_map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

map_process.php

```
################ Save & delete markers #################
if($_POST) //run only if there's a post data
{
//make sure request is comming from Ajax
$xhr = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest'; 
if (!$xhr){ 
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Error: Request must come from Ajax!'); 
    exit(); 
}

// get marker position and split it for database
$mLatLang   = explode(',',$_POST["latlang"]);
$mLat       = filter_var($mLatLang[0], FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT);
$mLng       = filter_var($mLatLang[1], FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT);

//Delete Marker
if(isset($_POST["del"]) && $_POST["del"]==true)
{
    $results = $mysqli->query("DELETE FROM markers WHERE lat=$mLat AND lng=$mLng");
    if (!$results) {  
      header('HTTP/1.1 500 Error: Could not delete Markers!'); 
      exit();
    } 
    exit("Done!");
}



$mName      = filter_var($_POST["name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$mAddress   = filter_var($_POST["address"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$mType      = filter_var($_POST["type"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);


//Update Marker
if(isset($_POST["update"]) && $_POST["update"]==true)
{
    $results = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO markers (lat, lng) VALUES ($mLat, $mLng) WHERE name=mytitle");
    if (!$results) {  
      header('HTTP/1.1 500 Error: Could not Update Markers!'); 
      exit();
    } 
    exit("Updated!");
}




$results = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO markers (name, address, lat, lng, type) VALUES ('$mName','$mAddress',$mLat, $mLng, '$mType')");
if (!$results) {  
      header('HTTP/1.1 500 Error: Could not create marker!'); 
      exit();
} 

$output = '<h1 class="marker-heading">'.$mName.'</h1><p>'.$mAddress.'</p>';
exit($output);
```

}

UPDATE//////////
i edited the code to show the current try im making. I can get the alert from update_marker that shows the latlng when the marker is moved or i can change it and get the title. those are working. i may not be sending the data correctly to map_process.php or getting it to select the right record. the delete and save querys run as they are in the post function and the update query is being called because i get the HTTP/1.1 500 Error: Could not Update Markers!' alert.

Comment: the logic seem correct .. could be yoh have some mistake  .. have you checked if the mLatLng in updateMarker contain a valid value?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue.  Could you describe your specific problem (other than it is "killing you")? Are you getting javascript errors? Is the AJAX request making it to the server?

Comment: If the insert and delete work .. then could be that the marker name is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out from this page -https://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/basic-php-mysqli-usage#update-a-record-  i wasnt using ticks around my update query! its the little things that kill

```
$results = $mysqli->query("UPDATE markers SET lat='$mLat', lng='$mLng' WHERE name='$mName'");
```